# Installing GA4 on Highlight theme on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I need to install GA4 code on my Wordpress website which has the 'Highlight' theme. There is no option in the theme file editor to install the code in the header.php file. Is there a way to install the code without having to use Google Tag Manager?

I tried to locate the file but it was present in other themes but not the Highlight theme. If I was to install the code in one of the other inactive themes, would the GA4 code gather data?

Comment: I think you would have better luck on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/